# Is there any way to change a single attribute of a template in a trigger in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, triggers

So I'm trying to get my TabItem to display a different image depending on whether it's selected or not.  Right now I've got it working using the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:UnselectedImageFilenameConverter x:Key="UnselectedImageFilenameConverter" />
    <local:SelectedImageFilenameConverter x:Key="SelectedImageFilenameConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Header, Converter={StaticResource UnselectedImageFilenameConverter}}" Stretch="None" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Header, Converter={StaticResource SelectedImageFilenameConverter}}" Stretch="None" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

However this seems quite redundant.  I'm changing the whole template when all I need is to change the image source.  It seems like there should be a more concise way of doing this, but so far no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a control template instead of a style.  In it, you can define a trigger which changes the image source according to your whim.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
    <Image x:Name="TabImage" Source="{Binding Something}"/>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="TabImage" Value="{Binding SomethingElse}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In the above template, if you want the template to be applied to every tab item by default, remove the x:Key attribute.

Comment: I had to change the Source bindings to `Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header, Converter={StaticResource UnselectedImageFilenameConverter}}"`, but once that was done it worked.